# MeasureIt is this a bug?

Tags: add-on, measurement

i try to measure my drawing with the "MeasureIt" Addon.
The measurement should look like "A".
The result is "B".
Ok i think, maybe that's because the Verts belong to two different faces.
So i copy the two Verts and separate them to a new Object ( "C"+ "D").
Then i go to Edit Mode, create an edge between the two verts and measure it.
The result is "E" !? Is this a Bug?

Blender Version: 2.79
"MeasureIt" Addon, Version 1.7.0

[image: Measure it Problem Example]

Comment: What addon settings do you use? If you measure using Y button then use Segment instead, X, Y or Z measure from vertex to origin as well (which in your case seems to be in the same place as center edge loop)

Comment: You're absolutely right, I see that now in the Button Popups,
Segment Button: "Add a new measure segment between 2 vertices"
X,Y,Z Button: "Add a new measure segment from vertex to object origin ..." Thank you, problem solved.